# SharePoint Date Shows as Number

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Regardless of what I do in SharePoint 2010, one of my calculated columns show date as a long integer. Please see screenshot.
[image]

My formula is below and it doesn't seem to respect it. I changed the column from date time to date. Created a new task and you see the date populates as I would want it on one of the tasks; but it doesn't for my older list items. Please advise.

```
=IF([Move to MTR2 Date]<>"",TEXT([Move to MTR2 Date],"mm/dd/yy"),IF([Move to MTR2?]=TRUE,"Requested",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Then get the date as

```
MONTH(date)&"/"&DAY(date)&"/"&YEAR(date)
```

Comment: it didn't work. I still see that long integer. Perhaps something to do with my column.